# Updating a File Script Issue

Tags: php

I'm using this code to update a given file;

```
<?php
if($_POST['submit']){
$open = fopen("textfile.php","w+");
$text = $_POST['update'];
fwrite($open, $text);
fclose($open);
echo "File updated.<br />"; 
echo "File:<br />";
$file = file("textfile.php");
foreach($file as $text) {
echo $text."<br />";
}
}else{
$file = file("textfile.php");
echo "<form action=\"".$PHP_SELF."\" method=\"post\">";
echo "<textarea Name=\"update\" cols=\"50\" rows=\"10\">";
foreach($file as $text) {
echo $text;
} 
echo "</textarea>";
echo "<input name=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Update\" />\n
</form>";
}

?>
```

But somehow its showing this error: [image]

Although the file does updated with this code when I submit my text and no error or submission, however the error its showing on the screenshot bugs me, so any way I could remove those errors?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider Googling the error message. There are bazillions of duplicates on Stack Overflow alone

Answer (score 0):

Change line 2 to this:
`if(isset($_POST['submit'])){`

Change line 15 to this:
`echo "<form action=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."\" method=\"post\">";`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your submit button is named `submit` checking for `$_POST['submit']` is unreliable (as not all browsers POST the submit button), you should check for another field name that is posted **OR** better yet, change to `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){`.

Also, `$PHP_SELF` is assuming you have register globals on (which shouldn't be), you should use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Joe has it.  You want isset().  @ (error suppression) is the coward's way out.  Be a man and use isset() ;-)